# SQL Server 2017 : Enable Automatic Tuning

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

We've moved to SQL Server 2017 and I wanted to run some performance metrics with and without SQL Server's new Automatic_Tuning setting.

I followed the advice here:
[Automatic Tuning From Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/automatic-tuning/automatic-tuning) and attempted to enable this in my SQL Management Studio New Query Window.

```
ALTER DATABASE current
SET AUTOMATIC_TUNING ( FORCE_LAST_GOOD_PLAN = ON );
```

This never successfully ran, I received a:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 6, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'AUTOMATIC_TUNING'.

Since this is a relatively new feature, I'm having trouble finding documents on it.  Is there anyone that can shed some light on how to enable this on a new database?

Comment: What is the current [compatibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database) of your database?

Comment: Are you certain that you have not confused the version of SSMS with the version of the connected sql server instance? What does "select @@version" return?

Comment: @SMor That's the answer right there.  SQL Server 2016, which explains why I don't have access to that function.  Thanks for the query, that's exactly the type of answer I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I ran the same script and the error was that Query Store is not enabled. So if you would like to use the facility you need to make sure the store in on and perhaps you could replace "current" with the exact name of your database.